# How can I place a view between cells in collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to place a view between cells in a collectionView. Like an ad. to be added dynamically after they see the first 3 cells. Is there a method to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could figure out a way to do that you still shouldn't. A collection view owns the area it draws in. It's in charge of placing cells where they belong within it's content view, and you are supposed to keep out.

That said, collection views are extremely flexible and you could design your collection view to display a set of "normal" cells, an ad cell, and then more normal cells. If your ad cells are different sizes or need to be spaced differently than your normal cells then you might have to create a custom collection view layout.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. But you can add a UICollectionViewCell which will contain advertisements or something else you want to be added. It is really simple. Just create two prototype cell. First cell will contain your data, second one will contain some extra data.